# Community user: "Waffle-trim"?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user, waffles

Experimenting with server-side spelling/grammar checking?

[image]

<sup>(Click for full size.)</sup>

[Source](https://serverfault.com/posts/112145/revisions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be because of [Anonymous edits](https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/929) are owned by [community user](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity).

[image]

[Here is revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/84916/revisions) of this answer by Community

Comment: Good catch, as usual! You have bionic eyes or something? ;-)

Comment: I thought waffles in this context was too esoteric, but I guess a Meta user forgot to log in. ;)