# Is it possible to change the user id in SO

Tags: support

My SO URL link is posted somewhere at a place which can reveal my personal information.

Is it possible that user id of my account so that when someone clicks there, it doesn't open my account?

Comment: Just curious: is this by any chance related to [Privacy leak in permalink?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink)

Comment: A mod could merge your account into a newly created one, if I'm not mistaken that would change your user id.

Comment: (As for [the edit history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/87710/revisions): I did not see [the new collision alert](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119) here...)

Comment: @Arjan, I guess he is *suggested*, not edited yet (it got submitted with your revision together), so may be that could be reason for no collision alert?

Comment: @YOU, given Community approved the suggested edit, it almost looks like I [used the improve button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86612/improve-can-fail-to-associate-the-approving-user-with-the-edit-record). Which I did not...

Comment: @Arjan, looks like "Improve" button just redirect to /edit page, so may be same mechanism at backend? unless they explicitly check the improve buttom clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a user can *change* the userID, as it's a 32-bit unsigned int that's created with a new account.

The solution I'm thinking would involve creating a new account (thus creating a new userID) and asking a SO moderator to merge your two accounts. Remember to state which userID you would like to remain. And note, that this causes a rep recount that may lead to rep loss, at certain situations.

Please, see [an FAQ answer about merging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) for an example.