# Community user approving edit suggestions without "improvement edit"

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bypassing the two-reviewer requirement for suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134579/bypassing-the-two-reviewer-requirement-for-suggested-edits)

Under unknown circumstances the community user seems to approve suggested edits, seemingly without interaction by a human user. For example these suggested edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50159
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50189

In both cases the community user is listed as (one of) the users that approved these edits.

The only case I know of in which this should happen is if a user chose to "Improve" the edit. But such an action should leave an additional entry in the revision history. For these suggested edits no "improvement edits" show up in the revision history, nevertheless they were approved by Community.

Anonymous approval like this should not be possible and it should be investigated how this could happen.

<sub>(It's probably not a reappearance of [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86612/improve-can-fail-to-associate-the-approving-user-with-the-edit-record): At least I get an error message when trying to submit an empty improvement.)</sub>

Comment: So, you didn't click "Improve" for [the second edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3885928/revisions)?

Comment: @Cody: I guess not - otherwise sth's edit should be about 1 second later than the suggested edit. (In fact, sth's edit is several minutes later.)

Comment: @Cody: No, I didn't. I found the question with the approved edit, decided to fix it up, and then later realized that the original edit suggestion was approved in suspicious circumstances.

Comment: Saw the other post before stumbling upon this one. (: