# Bypassing the two-reviewer requirement for suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

This is regarding the pending/suggested edit links that are seen along with questions themselves (**not** the ones in the edit queue which 5K+ users can see). When they read `edit(0)` and I approve them, they turn into `edit(1)` and I get a message like

> Approval from one more reviewer required.

Fine. But if I instead select "Improve" for one of them, **don't improve the post in any way** and simply submit, the system just accepts the edit in the name of the user who suggested it, thereby bypassing the "two reviews required" stipulation.

The same doesn't happen from the edit queue which 5k+ users can access. If I choose "Improve" there and try submitting without any edits from my side, I get a message like

> Error: Nothing edited. Can't submit.

Is this a bug? Are any devs looking into this?

Comment: Sounds like it's a bug, since the same doesn't happen when reviewing from the edit queue.

Comment: I guess what happens is that since you clicked improve, the system thinks the edit is now by a 2K+ user, and not by the original editor. If that's the case, great catch ;)

Comment: Related, solved earlier issue: [“Improve” can fail to associate the approving user with the edit record](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86612/improve-can-fail-to-associate-the-approving-user-with-the-edit-record/86613#86613).

Comment: (And as an aside: [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) Right.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was happening for suggested edits that modified the tags of the question.  We weren't correctly checking these tags when validating the edit after someone clicked improve.

This will be fixed with our next deploy. (newer than rev 2012.6.11.2879)

Comment: First day on the job as a dev, eh? Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance @Rebecca but what does `2879` mean here? And how does that translate to the time when the deployment will be made? Are there anyways that users can come to know of the deploy history?

Comment: @PavanManjunath check out the footer (on the right).  We list a revision number there.  Every time we build, that number changes to the new revision number.

Comment: the first item is time (20:12) than the date of the deploy: 6th Nov 2879, am I right?