# Update profile description for Community user to include suggested edits from anonymous users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, community-user, anonymous

When an anonymous user makes a suggested edit, it appears to be made by the Community user. When this happened to me, I was very confused, because the changes didn't look like they could have been made by an automated process.

I suggest two changes: update the Community user's profile description and make it more obvious that the change was really an anonymously suggested edit.

Here's the [current profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep Stack Overflow clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

I suggest you add another bullet point:

- Own suggested edits from anonymous users

Here's [the revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/983430/3) that was from an anonymous user. The only hint is the word "suggested" near the time stamp. If you click on it, it takes you to a page that says "proposed... by an anonymous user".

Some related questions:

- [Community♦ user edit: How does it know what to edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75472/131335)
- [Since when did the Community user become sentient?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104318/131335)
- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/131335)
- Also, [waffle trim?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84915/131335)

Comment: [You think *you* were confused... :)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/since-when-did-the-community-user-become-sentient)

Comment: I _think_ I was confused. Thanks for the link, I added it to the list of related questions. Seems like it should be pretty easy to clarify this one and reduce confusion.

Comment: +1 But I also have an alternative proposal: Rename Community to Skynet, and be done with it...

Comment: I think so far, the name [Eliza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) would be more appropriate, @Zaphod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This description update will go out with the next build.